# looking to apply T for dictionary value

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core

I have below OSM material data structure that is different than entities and i have methods inside entities which i am forming compatible OSM material using `AddToOsm` method

```
public class FenestrationMaterial : Material
{  }    
public class StandardOpaqueMaterial : OpaqueMaterial
{  }
public class OpaqueMaterial : Material
{  }

public class SurfaceConstruction : IIdentity<Guid>
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid SurfaceTypeId { get; set; }
    public IntendedSurfaceType SurfaceType { get; set; }
    public List<Guid> LayerIds { get; set; }

    public Construction AddToOsm(Model model, APIDbContext dbContext)
    {      
        var construction = new Construction(model);
        using var materials = new MaterialVector();
        var fenestrationMaterialById = new Dictionary<Guid, FenestrationMaterial>();
        var standardOpaqueMaterialById = new Dictionary<Guid, StandardOpaqueMaterial>();
        var opaqueMaterialById = new Dictionary<Guid, OpaqueMaterial>();
        foreach (var materialId in LayerIds.Where(i => i != default))
        {
            if (ProjectUtils.EntityById<OpaqueProjectMaterial>(dbContext, materialId) != default)
            {
                var OpaqueProjectMaterial = ProjectUtils.EntityById<OpaqueProjectMaterial>(dbContext, materialId);
                materials.Add(
                    standardOpaqueMaterialById.GetOrCreate(OpaqueProjectMaterial.Id, () => OpaqueProjectMaterial.AddToOsm(model))
                    );
                continue;
            }
            if (ProjectUtils.EntityById<AirGapMaterial>(dbContext, materialId) != default)
            {
                var airGapMaterial = ProjectUtils.EntityById<AirGapMaterial>(dbContext, materialId);
                materials.Add(
                    opaqueMaterialById.GetOrCreate(airGapMaterial.Id, () => airGapMaterial.AddToOsm(model))
                    );
                continue;
            }
            if (ProjectUtils.EntityById<GlazingMaterial>(dbContext, materialId) != default)
            {
                var glazingMaterial = ProjectUtils.EntityById<GlazingMaterial>(dbContext, materialId);
                materials.Add(
                    fenestrationMaterialById.GetOrCreate(glazingMaterial.Id, () => glazingMaterial.AddToOsm(model))
                    );
                continue;
            }              
        }
        construction.setLayers(materials);
        return construction;
    }
}
```

and then i do have entities for `airGapmaterial`, `OpaqueProjectMaterial` and `GlazingMaterial`

```
public class AirGapMaterial : ISourceOfData, IIdentity<Guid>
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ......
    ......
    public OpaqueMaterial AddToOsm(Model model)
    {
        if (model is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(model));
        }
        var airGapMaterial = new AirGap(model);
        airGapMaterial.setName(this.Name);
        .......
        return airGapMaterial;
    }
}       
public class GlazingMaterial : ISourceOfData, IIdentity<Guid>
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    .......
    ......
          
    public FenestrationMaterial AddToOsm(Model model)
    {
        if (model is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(model));
        }
        var glazingMaterialComplexModel = new StandardGlazing(model);
        glazingMaterialComplexModel.setName(this.Name);
        ........
        return glazingMaterialComplexModel;
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can use generic variable in-place of `FenestrationMaterial` and `StandardOpaqueMaterial` in the initialization of dictionaries (`fenestrationMaterialById, standardOpaqueMaterialById`)  and extract the below common methods into single one?

I am looking kind of like this if possible

```
var fenestrationMaterialById = new Dictionary<Guid, T>();
```

Comment: `OpaqueProjectMaterial` isn't defined. I assume it's derived from `ISourceOfData, IIdentity<Guid>` per the second code block?

Comment: Ok so you have 2 problems. The first is that the various `ISourceOfData` types are not related beyond the two database related interfaces. Looking at the example you want `AddToOsm` called on each - so define an interface with that function and add it to each. At this point you can declare a single generic type and store references to each and be able to invoke the method.....

Comment: The second issue is the dictionaries themselves. You have 3, each with a Guid and an Instance of a defined type - 3 elements. Moving to a single dictionary means you now only have 2 slots to fit the 3 things, you are going to loose something important, either the Guid or the actual Type. This may not be a problem for your case but if it is you will need a data structure that can handle it.

Comment: @asawyer, OpaqueProjectmaterial is same type of Glazingmaterial

Comment: i cannot change the data structure for `FenestrationMaterial` and other two defined types. so with this is it possible to do the same

Comment: I was talking about the `ISourceOfData` objects not the ones deriving from `Material`. If you can't change them you could always wrap them in another type you can change and implement the new `ICanAddToOsm` interface there instead would be an option, or perhaps adding some derived types and implementing it there.

Comment: I am thinking add to like this `public interface IMaterial<T>  {
        <T> AddToOsm<T>(Model model);
    }` but getting an error and the return type of method is not the same, so i have used generic parameter

Comment: for now i am just looking to combine these two into one if possible `if (ProjectUtils.EntityById<GlazingMaterial>(dbContext, materialId) != default)
            {
                var glazingMaterial = ProjectUtils.EntityById<GlazingMaterial>(dbContext, materialId);
                materials.Add(
                    fenestrationMaterialById.GetOrCreate(glazingMaterial.Id, () => glazingMaterial.AddToOsm(model))
                    );
                continue;
            } `

Comment: @asawyer, i am looking how is this possible with the above methods `At this point you can declare a single generic type and store references to each and be able to invoke the method.....`

Comment: atleast combining these methods inside foreach `if(ProjectUtils.EntityById<OpaqueMaterial>(dbContext, materialId) != default)
 {
         var opaqueMaterial = ProjectUtils.EntityById<OpaqueMaterial>(dbContext,materialId);
          materials.Add(standardOpaqueMaterialById.GetOrCreate(opaqueMaterial.Id, () => opaqueMaterial.AddToOsm(model)));
           continue;
    }
    ......`

Comment: i have added like this to class `public class GlazingMaterial : ISourceOfData, IIdentity<Guid>, IMaterial<FenestrationMaterial>` and for the interface  `public interface IMaterial<out T>
    {
        public T AddToOsm(Model model);
    }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232308/discussion-between-enigma-state-and-asawyer).

Answer (score 0):

That took a bit longer then I expected. Turns out the `ProjectUtils` bit really does throw a wrench into the works. In the following I trimmed things down to just the core concepts, added types missing from your post and did some refactoring to try and stream line things as much as possible. There is still plenty of room for improvement.

I also had to make a ton of assumptions about the underlying data and undocumented components. It looks to me like it would do what you're looking for but its certainly possible that I've made an assumption that is breaking on your end. I also tried to follow the pattern with the `Util` and `DbContext` usage, however, to me, those look pretty weak and should probably be reworked.

The core section you wanted to refactor is now:

```
public Construction AddToOsm(APIDbContext dbContext, Model model, IEnumerable<Guid> ids)
{
    if(model is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(model));

    var materialSources = ids.Where(i => i != default)
        .Select(i => _projectUtils.EntityById<SourceData>(dbContext, i))
        .Select(i => _projectUtils.ResolveToMaterialSource(i));

    using var materialVector = new MaterialVector();
    foreach (var materialSource in materialSources)
    {
        materialVector.Add(materialSource.AddToOsm(model));
    }
    return new Construction(model, materialVector);
}
```

And here's the rest, it should compile.

```
public class Model { }

public class Construction
{
    public Construction(Model model, MaterialVector materials)
    {
        SetLayers(materials);
    }

    internal void SetLayers(MaterialVector materials)
    {
    }
}

public interface ISourceOfData 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IIdentity<T> 
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class IntendedSurfaceType { }

public class APIDbContext { }

public class KeyAttribute : Attribute { }

public class MaterialVector : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    internal void Add(IMaterial p)
    {
    }
}

public interface IMaterialTypeResolver
{
    public IMaterialSource ResolveType(SourceData i);
}

public class MaterialTypeResolver : IMaterialTypeResolver
{
    public IMaterialSource ResolveType(SourceData sourceData)
    {
        //Problem here - I don't know how your ProjectUtils.EntityById works internally
        //So I'm guessing here that it uses a factory pattern

        //this method needs to return an IMaterialSource...
        //GlazingMaterialSource
        //AirGapMaterialSource
        //ect ect
        //for a given set of database values
        
        //essentially you need something coming from the database to tell the code
        //which type to create, we pass that the data base values
        //and it passes them later to the IMaterial in the AddToOsm call
        //so the IMaterial implementation can do whatever custom work
        return new OpaqueProjectMaterialSource(sourceData);
    }
}

public class ProjectUtils
{
    private IMaterialTypeResolver _MaterialTypeResolver;
    
    public ProjectUtils(IMaterialTypeResolver materialTypeResolver)
    {
        _MaterialTypeResolver = materialTypeResolver;
    }

    public T EntityById<T>(APIDbContext dbContext, Guid materialId) where T : new()
        //here you'd use the dbContext to populated this
        //though this one at a time stuff is pretty inefficient
        //it should be done as a single query if possible
        => new T();
        
    public IMaterialSource ResolveToMaterialSource(SourceData i) => _MaterialTypeResolver.ResolveType(i);
}

public interface IMaterial
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
}

public abstract class MaterialBase : IMaterial 
{ 
    public string Name {get;set;}
    
    public MaterialBase(Model model, ISourceOfData source)
    {
        this.Name = source.Name;
    }   
}

public class AirGapMaterial : MaterialBase
{
    public AirGapMaterial(Model model, ISourceOfData source) : base(model, source)
    {    
    }
}

public class StandardGlazingMaterial : MaterialBase
{
    public StandardGlazingMaterial(Model model, ISourceOfData source) : base(model, source)
    {
    }
}

public class FenestrationMaterial : MaterialBase
{
    public FenestrationMaterial(Model model, ISourceOfData source) : base(model, source)
    {
    }
}

public class StandardOpaqueMaterial : OpaqueMaterial
{
    public StandardOpaqueMaterial(Model model, ISourceOfData source) : base(model, source)
    {
    }
}

public class OpaqueMaterial : MaterialBase
{
    public OpaqueMaterial(Model model, ISourceOfData source) : base(model, source)
    {
    }
}

public class SurfaceConstruction : IIdentity<Guid>
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    private ProjectUtils _projectUtils;
    
    public SurfaceConstruction(ProjectUtils projectUtils)
    {
        _projectUtils = projectUtils;
    }

    public Construction AddToOsm(APIDbContext dbContext, Model model, IEnumerable<Guid> ids)
    {
        if(model is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(model));
        
        var materialSources = ids.Where(i => i != default)
            .Select(i => _projectUtils.EntityById<SourceData>(dbContext, i))
            .Select(i => _projectUtils.ResolveToMaterialSource(i));

        using var materialVector = new MaterialVector();
        foreach (var materialSource in materialSources)
        {
            materialVector.Add(materialSource.AddToOsm(model));
        }
        return new Construction(model, materialVector);
    }
}

public interface IMaterialSource
{
    public IMaterial AddToOsm(Model model);
}

public class SourceData : ISourceOfData, IIdentity<Guid>
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    //add all the database loaded properties here
}

public abstract class MaterialSourceBase : IMaterialSource
{
    protected SourceData SourceData {get;set;}
    
    protected MaterialSourceBase(SourceData sourceData)
    {
        SourceData = sourceData;
    }
    
    public abstract IMaterial AddToOsm(Model model);
}

//So at this point you could generalize all of this down to a single
//factory pattern backed function as all we care about are
//given a set of database values, give me an IMaterial
public class OpaqueProjectMaterialSource : MaterialSourceBase
{
    public OpaqueProjectMaterialSource(SourceData sourceData) : base(sourceData)
    {
    }
    
    public override IMaterial AddToOsm(Model model) => new StandardOpaqueMaterial(model, base.SourceData);
}

public class AirGapMaterialSource : MaterialSourceBase
{
    public AirGapMaterialSource(SourceData sourceData) : base(sourceData)
    {
    }
    
    public override IMaterial AddToOsm(Model model) => new AirGapMaterial(model, base.SourceData);
}

public class GlazingMaterialSource : MaterialSourceBase
{
    public GlazingMaterialSource(SourceData sourceData) : base(sourceData)
    {
    }
    
    public override IMaterial AddToOsm(Model model) => new StandardGlazingMaterial(model, base.SourceData);
}
```

Comment: sorry for the delay,  forgot to inform these classes "construction", "Materialvector" , "fenestration material", "StandardGlazingMaterial " are imported from third part library and i cannot control over them

Comment: and this is code for project utils                                                                                    
       `public static T EntityById<T>(APIDbContext dbContext, Guid id) where T : class, IIdentity<Guid>
       => dbContext?.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);`

Comment: looks like "SourceData" class is inheriting from IsourceOfData, IIdentity only those are common for different materials and do have different properties for different materials as well.

Comment: i believe it is not possible to combine into single  without modifying the third party library classes mentioned above

Comment: and IsourceOfData is haaving only this fields `public interface ISourceOfData
    {
        public Guid? SourceOfDataId { get; set; }
        public CodeStandardGuideline SourceOfData { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: what are the remaining properties to include here in sourceOfData  `//add all the database loaded properties here`